# Боковое меню MenuItem clickListener

Tags: android, меню

[Github](https://github.com/kofnal/NavigationApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/app/fil/navigationapp/MainActivity.java)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home,  R.id.nav_slideshow,
            R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            System.out.println("onNavigationItemSelected in class "+menuItem.toString());
            return false;});
//View menuItem = findViewById(R.id.nav_tools);
//        System.out.println("r-t-r "+menuItem.toString());
//        menuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
//                System.out.println("menu7778 99 "+menuItem.toString());
//                return false;
//            }
//        });
//        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
//            @Override
//            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
//                System.out.println("menu7778 99 "+menuItem.toString());
////                onNavigationItemSelected(menuItem);
////                super.notify();
//                return true;
//            }
//        });
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        System.out.println("onNavigationItemSelected @Override"+menuItem.toString());
        return true;
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста почему здесь
55 строчка
View menuItem = findViewById(R.id.nav_tools);
не может найти объект и выдаёт NULL?
или как назначить R.id.nav_tools какой-нибудь обработчик нажатия?
Это стандартное боковое меню из студии.
.setOnMenuItemClickListener переопределяет всю стандартную работу бокового меню. Не могу найти нигде как вернуть работу супер метода.
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected вообще не срабатывает...

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
MenuItem menuItem = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_tools);
    menuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            System.out.println("ItemClickListener "+menuItem.toString());
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
    });
```